# Oracle SQL to retrieve data based on record movement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data as below:

```
Table abc
    product_id      shelf_number     moved_date
    123             1                01-Jan-18
    123             2                02-Jan-18 
    456             1                01-Jan-18
    678             1                01-Jan-18
    123             3                03-Jan-18 
    789             2                01-Jan-18
    789             1                02-Jan-18
```

I am using Oracle and need to retrieve product_id which has been moved from shelf number 1 to 2 in sequence according to moved_date.

Only product_id 123 fulfill the criteria as product_id 123 has been moved from shelf_number 1 to 2 in order according to moved_date.

Product_id 789 should be excluded as it has been moved from shelf_number 2 to 1 which violate the criteria.

Any idea on the SQL to achieve that? Is there any analytic function in Oracle P/L SQL that easily do this? Thanks.

Thank you,

Hatjhie

Comment: What is your expected result? Just one record with the product number, or something else?

Comment: Thanks for your queries. The expected result is only Product 123 as that's the only one fulfill the criteria.

Comment: And why 456 and 678 do not fulfill the criteria?

Comment: 456 and 678 are never moved from shelf_number 1 to 2. It does not meet the criteria, hence it will be excluded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(shelf_number) over (partition by product_id order by moved_date) as prev_shelf_number
      from t
     ) t
where prev_shelf_number = 1 and shelf_number = 2;
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This can help

```
select * from tbl a where exists(select 1 from tbl b where a.product_id = b.product_id      
 and b.shelf_number = 2 and a.moved_date > b.moved_date) and and a.shelf_number = 1
```